# Additional meaning of the verb "rotar" in Latin America?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, verbos, significado

I heard the verb `rotar` and `rotarlo` in contexts where neither rotate nor turn nor roll seems to make sense. `return` possibly, but I do not understand spanish well enough. I believe they where talking about people and their possibly dangerous actions.

I could not find additional meanings for this verb on the web.

Is there another use of `rotar` or `rotarlo` is Latin America besides what suggests mechanical circular motion? like something abstract? Or did I mishear or misunderstood some similar sounding word?

Comment: From http://bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rotar, "En la jerga de los beodos, circular una botella para que el licor sea libado de manera equitativa entre la concurrencia". Also, `rotar` can sometimes mean in Spain (don't know if in other countries) "to wish" in a colloquial way. Example: "Si me rota, lo mismo me pongo a tocar el piano".

Comment: @fedorqui "to wish" is likely what I am looking for, thanks

Comment: OK! I am adding this as an answer, so that you can mark as accepted if it solves your question.

Comment: @foo You should have given us an example of the use you are looking for. Anyway, if fedorqui has already found out what you wanted, that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

In a colloquial context you can also listen to `rotar` meaning **`"to wish"`**, at least in Spanish from Spain.

For example:

> Si me rota, lo mismo me pongo a tocar el piano

meaning

> If I wish, I may start playing the piano

Apparently, it comes from the Catalan [`rodar`](http://diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0120153), "2. Donar la gana" -> "Dar la gana" -> "to wish".

Comment: Never heard here (Argentina)

Comment: Never heard and I'm from Spain, I guess its use is regional

Comment: @JesusS I found out it comes from Catalan: http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0120153 "2. Donar la gana" -> "Dar la gana" -> "to wish".

Answer (score 2):

In Perú we use it colloquial to express the desire for sharing something.

> Rota el vaso.
>   Pass the glass (among a group of people using the
>   same glass)

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of Mexico, the word **rotar** can also be used when players in a Volleyball team switch positions during the match.

The other expressions listed here are not very common, but might come out in a creative, alcohol-driven night...

Comment: Also used in soccer.

Comment: Yes, in fact it is the second meaning in [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=rotar): _2. intr. Seguir un turno en cargos, comisiones, etc._

Answer (score 1):

It has to so with circular motion, but also applies to the following examples:

> rota el cuaderno.
>
> rota la tapa de la botella.
>
> debes rotarlo para que funcione.

Basically, **rotar** stands also in spanish for **giro** (turn), so there's no exceptional way to use these verbs whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **rotar** is **always** related to the movement which is regularly **to roll around one axis**. For example **rotate** an image clockwise or counterwise.

> According to our Royal Spanish Academy dictionnary it also means
>   **to burp** but it's not common.

There is another sense for **rotar** in Latin America. It also means to shift work places or to swap tires in the same car or another. It's like **exchange**.

Example 1: **Yo roto las llantas de mi auto.** (I swap the tires of my car) In this case could be that I change places of each tire in order to avoid wastage from just one side of the tire.

Example 2:
**En nuestra compañía rotamos horarios** (In our company we shift turns) In this case could be used as a work shifts. I work 4 hours on the same task then I rest 4 hours while a co-worker replaces me on the same task. This is also used in mining when people works 15 days and rest 15 days with their families. They have a **rotation** schedule.

In case of **rotarlo** according to your context could be **change its(something) position or replace it**.

Maybe it would be useful if you can add the whole context for your word in order to give more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After hearing it in several conversations I figured out that it must mean "beat" or "defeat", hence it was "derrotar".

Comment: So the question is totally wrong with word you are currently using. Anyway, "derrotar" is as you said to defeat.